# Perl WriteExcel - рандомное имя для формируемого файла

Tags: perl

Скрипт Perl выгружает данные в excel файл:
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('/u03/report/result.xlsx');
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы имя файла задавалось не конкретное, как result в моем случае, а рандомное или например, result-jsdnfks.xlsx, result-abcjhsb.xlsx(т е по маске)?

Comment: Используйте например текущее время (`time()`) в качестве имени. Или вам принципиально что бы в имени был набор букв ?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp или gettimeofday из Time::HiRes

Answer (score 0):

В линуксе есть чудесная функция mktemp. Она генерирует уникальное имя. И в перле есть обертки для ее использования https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html